# Обновить данные пользователя с Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Здравствуйте, мне нужно обновить данные пользователя с помощью `Identity`. Есть такой метод контролера :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(WDetailsModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
    try
    {
        var upd_user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            About = model.About,
            City = model.City,
            Country = model.Country,
            FName = model.F_Name,
            LName = model.L_Name,
            WebSite = model.WebSite,
            Phone = model.Phone,
            Email = model.Email,
        };
        var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(upd_user);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                foreach (var err in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", err);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Result = "Новые данные сохранены";
                return View();
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Однако при попытке сохранить изменения получаю ошибку :

> Name cannot be null or empty.

Если же поставить `UserName`, тем же что и у текущего `User.Identity.Name` выпадет ошибка о том, что пользователь с таким именем уже существует. Логично но я же использую `UpdateAsync` а не `CreateAsync`. Может вообще все неправильно сделал ? Подскажите. И связанный вопрос - по умолчанию `Identity` создает 6 таблиц при первом запуске - юзеры, клеймы, роли, миграции и т.д. Вопрос - если мне нужно создать еще несколько таблиц и работать с ними как поступить ? Нужно написать класс-модель этих таблиц ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так если вы пытаетесь у какого-то пользователя изменить имя на то, которое уже занято то и ругается, и так и должно быть, просто используйте уникальные имена.

И да, для ваших личных классов создавайте свои классы модели и прописывайте их в стиле EF Code First

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Class1> Class1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class2> Class2s { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

**Обновлено:**

Я обновление делаю обычно так:

```
ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel userViewModel ) {
   var userOld = db.Users.Find(userViewModel.UserName);
   if(userOld ==null) return null; // тут нужно статус код вернуть
   userOld.Name = userViewModel.Name;
   userOld.SomeField = userViewModel.SomeField;
   // ...
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: В том то и дело что поле `UserName` я даже не трогаю (посмотрите внимательно). Вот например `City`, ` WebSite`, `About` и тд - поля которые я определил дополнительно их и хочу обновить.

Comment: @Сергей Так его надо задать и не нулевым, нулевым он быть не может, и при этом он должен быть уникален. Часто туда например email пишут, для уникальности.

Comment: Если я его задаю то выпадет ошибка о том, что пользователь с таким именем уже существует.

Comment: @Сергей напишите туда например `Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: @Сергей Вам надо определиться с логикой, если вы обновляете уже существующие данные, то сначала надо найти запись в таблице, в неё уже есть UserName и после этого обновить значения. Если вы создаёте нового пользователя, тогда нужно ему дань новое уникальное имя.

Comment: @Сергей Сейчас в ответ пример скину.

Comment: В самом начале написано `обновить данные пользователя`, зачем мне новый `Guid` ? В таблице `AspNetUsers` есть строка с данными пользователя, я хочу обновить один из столбцов - все.

Comment: @Сергей я написал пример в ответе

Comment: db - обьект `IdentityDbContext`  ?

Comment: @Сергей да. Обычное даже ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext. Класс контекста для проекта обычно делается свой но наследуется от IdentityDbContext

Comment: немного не понял - а через `UserManager` нельзя обновить ? У него же метод `UpdateAsync` для этого  или....

Comment: @Сергей Можно и через него. Но смысл тот же что сначала надо его получить а потом тот который получил - обновить. А то в вашем коде как система догадается какого именно пользователя обновлять? он скорее всего на вашу конструкцию хочет его создать нового...

Comment: @Сергей вы в своём коде нового создаёте юзера, а нужно получить того который уже есть...

Comment: да. действительно, кажется понял ошибку. сейчас попробую

Comment: Все правильно,надо было просто найти пользователя и поменять его свойства! глупая ошибка однако. И еще - как я понимаю что бы  контекст `DbSet<Class1>` создал новые таблицы в БД необходимо выполнить миграцию , через  консоль или есть какая тотдельная процедура?

Comment: @Сергей да, но для тестового периода проще делать через DropCreateIfModelChanges как-то так называется. Вообщем для этапа разработки каждый раз заного пересоздаёт базу автоматически, если схема изменена.

Comment: С Identity бывали проблемы по части пересоздания БД. даже стандартной с 6 тбл. Попробую и так и так. Спасибо!